# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess - connections not disposing on Oracle error

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, connection, pooling

We have a WCF search service hosted in IIS7 which takes hints from a client application, generates the SQL, queries the Oracle back end and returns a JSON result.

Our provider is Oracle.ManagedDataAcces 12.1.2400.

We recently ran into a log jam where requests were timing out waiting for a pooled connection.  The exception was
"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: Pooled connection request timed"

We finally discovered that just prior to the connection pooling error, exceptions had been logged where a user request was resulting in a malformed SQL statement resulting in an ORA-00904 (Invalid Identifier) exception.  Once we got the user to stop submitting the request over and over the pooled connection timeouts ceased.

Now my bigger concern is why connections were not being released when an Oracle exception occurred.  I've been through our data access layer and all IDisposable classes from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess are encased in Using blocks.

First, here's our connection string.

```
User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Data Source=MyOracleDB;Max Pool Size=10;Min Pool Size=5;Connection Lifetime=120;Enlist=true;Pooling=true;
```

Now this is an application I inherited, so I have no idea why Enlist=True since this app should not be participating in any distributed trans.

Here's some of the code from our data access layer.  The GetDataSet method does most of the heavy lifting.

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyOrganization.Services.DataAccess.Oracle
{
    /// <summary>An Oracle data source</summary>
    public class Database : IDataSource
    {
        private readonly IConnectionStringHandler connectionStringHandler;
        public Database(IConnectionStringHandler connectionStringHandler)
        {
            this.connectionStringHandler = connectionStringHandler;
        }
        public Database() { }

        #region IDataSource Members

        private string connectionString;

        /// <summary>The connection string.</summary>
        /// <value>Returns the value of <paramref name="connectionString"/></value>
        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            if (connectionStringHandler != null)
            {
                return connectionStringHandler.ConnectionString;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
                {
                    return connectionString;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("No connection handler or connection string set");
                }
            }
        }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            set { connectionString = value; }
        }

        **private OracleConnection connection**;
....

        public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql)
        {
            using (connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                using (OracleCommand command = PrepareCommand(sql) as OracleCommand)
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;

                    using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                        adapter.Fill(ds);

                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The only thing that gives me the slightest pause is the OracleConnection object being a class member instead of a local variable.  Could that cause it to not be disposed of properly when there's a SQL error?

Comment: connections are not actually released, they are pooled. The point of pooling is that the connections are waiting and available. I don't think you have a Dispose problem. I'm no dba but a max pool size of 10 seems very small.

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong term, I mean let go of the connection so it's available for another request to use.  Ten had been sufficient for years until this error cropped up.  We did increase it (to 100, I think), but we seemed to still have problems after that.  Hard to say since I have no access to the production server and haven't been able to replicate in dev.